# Javascript parse text assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would love some advice. I'm trying to get some text out of a long string. The string is here: http://espn.go.com/nba/bottomline/scores

I have the script that makes an HTTP request to get all this text, but need help only taking certian things from this long string.

I would like to grab this text from the long string:

```
Cleveland%20114%20%20%20LA%20Clippers%2090%20(FINAL)
Indiana%20at%20Atlanta%20(6:00%20PM%20ET)
Utah%20at%20Sacramento%20(6:00%20PM%20ET)
Milwaukee%20at%20Brooklyn%20(8:00%20PM%20ET)
New%20York%20at%20LA%20Lakers%20(9:30%20PM%20ET)
```

I'm not sure the best way to go about it.. Should I try to grab the text between each `nba_s_left1=` and `&`. If so, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the whole long string is one big query string. So you can parse it with this js function:

```
function parseQuery(qstr) {
        var query = {};
        var a = qstr.substr(1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            var b = a[i].split('=');
            query[decodeURIComponent(b[0])] = decodeURIComponent(b[1] || '');
        }
        return query;
    }
query = parseQuery(longString);
```

And then you can just get the part, that interests you, by calling `query["nba_s_left1"]`